# how do I return a variable outside an onload function?

Tags: javascript

```
request.onload = function () {
   let avg = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
};
```

This is my side. I have declared a global variable elsewhere. This function is supposed to update the variable so I can use the "updated"  'avg' elsewhere. Can anyone help me to return the variable outside the function?

Comment: You need to return that avg variable?

Comment: Put the code that needs that value inside your `onload` function and/or call other functions from there and pass the value. The value will become available *on load*, **sometime later**. You cannot return it *right now*. Other code that needs the value needs to await the `load` event to happen first, which is exactly why you attach a *callback function* to it.